# Database schema versioning control (not change script version control)

Tags: oracle, database-migration, liquibase

Want to get some advise on database version control tools , my requirement is version control database schema only not any data . Those tools like liquibase or flyway are targeting version migration script not actually db schema and trying to handle both schema and data changes . They maintain a changelog/version table in database side and must keep change script/sql as immutable . From version control and single source state point of view I don't consider it is good idea .

Tool like [Pyrseas](https://github.com/perseas/Pyrseas) looks good to me , it only keep single state as source (yaml) . Once yaml get changed it will generate the SQL to maintain DB as expect state , however it only support postgresql .

Any other open source tool can do it in same manner as Pyrseas but also support Oracle , mysql and so on ? Again manage final db schema state rather change script is what I preferred .

Thanks

Comment: Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As you're using Oracle, have you looked at EBR = Edition-Based Redefinition? This is a kind of versioning for schemas that lets you switch between versions while the database is live. It gets complicated quickly though. http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_editions.htm

Comment: If EBR is more of db side of thing it may not be the option for me , I would rather than manage everything from source code  , it is part of my CI nature , I will have a look anyway , Thanks

Comment: Puppet and similar dev-ops tool were built on the similar idea you describe the desired state of the system and they find the way to reach it from the current one. Maybe they have database schema modules you need.

Comment: As far as I know puppet and ansible don't  have schema module doing it this way , 3rd party module like  [puppet-database_schema](https://github.com/cpitman/puppet-database_schema) is actually use flyway or liquibase , which is manage migration not schema itself , Thanks